# Словообразовательная цепочка глагола "полыхать"-"всполыхнуть"

Tags: словообразование

Пожалуйста, скажите, как продолжить словообразовательную цепочку слов: *полыхать...всполыхнуть*?

Answer (score 2):

> как продолжить словообразовательную цепочку слов:
>   *полыхать...всполыхнуть*?

Продолжить вряд ли возможно, а вот недостающее звено добавить в цепочку можно:

***полых***ать -> полых-**ну**-ть -> **вс**-полыхнуть